# Setting a custom Style to an Action Bar.xml

Tags: android

I created a custom style for my action bar on my android project:

```
<!-- Style for the Login Menu Toolbar -->
<style name="LoginMenu">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/menu</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/menuFont</item>
</style>
```

And I have a Action Bar.xml which I want to add this style:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" > 
</menu>
```

As you can see, the xml file with the action bar is empty right now, and I can't figure how to add the style to it...

My objective is to create a custom Action Bar with different background colors, how should I do this?

Comment: Android Action bar is no more in use. Toolbar is used in place of action bar. You can use tool bar.
If u want toolbar I can tell u how can it be achieved

Comment: I can't really say the difference between them, maybe what I really want is a Toolbar and I'm refering it as an Action Bar, can you explain how to do with a toolbar please?

Comment: Yeah wait 2 min. I'm writing code for u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for you. You can change the colors of toolbar in colors.xml.
colorPrimary is for ToolBar and colorPrimaryDark is for status bar

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.newapp.toolbarwork.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

   <!-- <include layout="@layout/content_main" />-->



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.newapp.toolbarwork;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
</resources>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Comment: It worked indeed. What I really wanted was a toolbar. Thank you!

Comment: No problem... Your problem is solved thats the main concern

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the following. You will need to ensure you have the `AppCompat` library dependency in your `gradle.build` file (i.e. `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'`, an example gradle file is [here](https://github.com/PPartisan/RunDo/blob/master/app/build.gradle))

First, ensure your app's theme has a `Theme.AppCompat.*` parent. Then, assign `colorPrimary` item with the preferred colour for your action bar. For example, in your `styles.xml`:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_action_bar_color</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Second, ensure that `AppTheme` is your application's theme in your `manifest`.

Finally, your `Activity` classes will need to extend `AppCompatActivity` rather than `Activity`.

Comment: That worked. But I have one more question, what if I want to customize the text of that Action Bar? Like align to center of the Bar, is that possible?

Comment: @F.Carvalho Yes, but for that level of customisation I would recommend you use a `Toolbar` - you can then control every aspect of its appearance.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this:

```
android:theme="@styles/LoginMenu"
```